# netbeans CSS control console

Tags: css, netbeans

I am learning CSS at the moment.

While using netBeans I noticed that there is a control console to the left of the main editor page that allows you to edit your CSS elements and properties. There are a series of drop-down menus for font etc.

I closed this by accident and can't find a way to reopen it.

I know this is a bit of a mundane question but can anyone help me reopen this most useful of consoles?

Comment: I found the answer to this.

Choose Window > Web > CSS Styles from the main menu to open the CSS Styles window if it is not already open

Comment: You can add the solution as an answer and accept it or you can remove this question

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. Choose Window > Web > CSS Styles from the main menu to open the CSS Styles window if it is not already open